# Change text field background color on UISearchBar with GoogleMaps API

Tags: ios, swift3

Is there anyway to change text field background color on UISearchBar? 
[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN8tf.png)
Here's my code : 
This is action function when the button clicked

```
func streetButtonOnPressed(){
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = .white
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .primary
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment
    filter.country = "SG"
    autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's the extension :

```
extension ManageListingsCreateListingPropertyLocationViewController : GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

// Handle the user's selection.
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}}
```

Is there anyway to solve this ? T.T